# How to create a singleton object for a whole application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm writing code to create an application using a singleton object.
When it will launch,

1. The problem is when I launch my application. It will create one object, and when I will press the back button, the application closes. And when I long press the home button and again start application, then it will create another object.
2. When I again launch the application by clicking on icon, it will generate another object.

But when I come out from the application by pressing the home button and again go to the application by long pressing the home button and launching application, then it will not create new objects.

Activity code:

```
package com.gmmusic.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class GmmusicActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String TAG = "GmmusicActivity";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i(TAG, "Created instance#"+ MyMainApplication.getInstance().count());
    }
}
```

Singleton code:

```
package com.gmmusic.test;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyMainApplication extends Application {

    private static String TAG = "MyMainApplication";

    private static MyMainApplication singleton;

    public static MyMainApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private int count1=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        singleton = this;
        Log.i(TAG, "Singleton created");
        System.out.println("count1 >> "+count1);
        count1++;
    }

    public int count() {
        return count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? When the app is no longer in memory a new object will be created, however when it is still in memory the existing one will be reused.

Comment: You want to save application context and load It after every app start, am I right? I think saving application instance that way is impossible. You don't need to use singleton at all. Save your application data using SharedPreferences and load It after every application start.

Comment: Henry: When app. is closed all object should not be kill and when again launch app. it will not create new object until i will not press 2 times on back button.

Comment: Skywall: Exactly i'm making a media player.when i close app. by clicking on back button it will come out and when i again launch it will create new object which will not happen. How can i resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements Serializeable:

```
class Person implements Serializeable
    String name;
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you have another intent, you can pass it and if you close this activity you can get the result back like this

```
Person p = new Person("Oliver");
Intent i = new Intent()
i.setClass(this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("person", p);
startActivityForResult(i,1) // 1 is ResultCode
```

Then in the other Activity, you can get this object, for example in the onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
     Person p = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");
     // The same string as in first_activity
}
```

After all this, you can do whatever you want with the same object and if you want to get back to the first activity, read *[Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to handle this behavior is by customizing activity's lunch mode attribute it the manifest file.
You would probably set it to SingleTop or SingleInstance depending on your application.
see the documentations : [Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)